# Tumblr URL Scheme

Tags: ios, tumblr, url-scheme

What is the iOS URL scheme for opening the Tumblr App to a specific blog url?

Seem to not be able to find this any where.

My guess is its something

```
tumblr://
```

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes link:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tumblr/id305343404?mt=8
```

Native application URL string example:

```
tumblr:///link?url=yourURL.com/tumblr/iphone&name=Midhun
```

Extended example:

```
tumblr:///link?url=yourURL.com/tumblr/iphone&name=Midhun tumblr:///text?title=Hello&body=World
```

Comment: For me, this successfully opened the Tumblr app but did not bring me to the correct post (or even to the correct blog within Tumblr). It just opened Tumblr to the main dashboard.

Comment: @Ryan The answer was posted back in 2012, may be the schemes changed. Please consider the time of the post before down voting.

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=[blogName]
```

If the blog is http://myblog.tumblr.com then the URL Scheme will be :

```
tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=myblog
```

Answer (score 0):

The following tips from [this page](http://whats12.tumblr.com/post/76942776770/url-schemes-tumblr-for-ios-exposes-actions-using) worked for me:

> Tumblr for iOS exposes actions using the [x-callback-url
>   specification](https://t.umblr.com/redirect?z=http%3A%2F%2Fx-callback-url.com%2F&t=ZTVlNDVmNWJjOGRkZDliZDA1MjEyNWZkOTc5OWI0YmM1NTAzMDRjZiw2amp4OWtaVw%3D%3D&b=t%3A6oaiHjl0XbjJ10ZmX0WgaQ&p=http%3A%2F%2Fwhats12.tumblr.com%2Fpost%2F76942776770%2Furl-schemes-tumblr-for-ios-exposes-actions-using&m=1). The TMTumblrAppClient class merely provides a
>   convenient interface on top of the following URLs:
>
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/dashboard
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/tag?tag=gif
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=bryan
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=bryan&postID=43724939726
>
> The post URLs below also support `x-success` and `x-cancel`
>   callback parameters:
>
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/text?title=Title&body=Body&tags=gif&tags=lol
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/quote?quote=Quote&source=Source
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/link?title=Bryan&url=bryan.io&description=Website
> - tumblr://x-callback-url/chat?title=Title&body=Body&tags=gif&tags=lol

Here is what worked: `<a href="tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=luxury-dream-homes&postID=173176271099">test this link</a>`

See also: https://engineering.tumblr.com/post/48855322178/tumblr-sdk-updates and https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK#url-schemes